# How to use unittest.mock package in both Python 3.8+ and Python 2.7+?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unittest

I am writing an API client library. The library is meant to support both Python 2.7+ and Python 3+.

Now writing the tests and trying to use `MagicMock` and `patch`. Based on the documentation here, https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/unittest.mock.html, there is a backport of `unittest.mock`, if I install `mock` (using `pip install mock==3.0.5`). But when I install it in my docker image, the line:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
```

still fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/library_wq-api-utils/wq_api_utils/tests/tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from unittest.mock import patch
ImportError: No module named mock
```

I might be confused here about the documentation, but any help making the same code run in both Python 2.7 and 3.8 would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I like that. Let me give it a shot thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use try-except:

```py
try:
    from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
except ImportError:
    from mock import patch, MagicMock
```

Answer (score 5):

**Python 2.x**

Use this import:

```
from mock import patch, MagicMock
```

**Python 3.3+**

`mock` has been included in the `unittest` module, and can be imported by:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
```

**Check python version at runtime**

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from mock import patch, MagicMock
if sys.version_info[0] > 3:
    from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
```

**What it's doing**

`sys.version_info[0]` is the major version number, where as `sys.version_info[1]` would give you the minor version number.

The python version check will check if it is python `2` or python `3`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my issue. I need the same code to be compatible with both versions - the whole point of the question is to enable me to run exactly the same code.

Comment: @SwaggaTing ah sorry I did not catch that part, I have edited my answer to include a python version check at runtime and import the correct package.

Comment: thanks this is what i meant! now i am wondering which answer is more "pythonic" - checking version, or using try/except..

Comment: The try/except looks cleaner. I think though if you were to revisit the code when another major python revision is released, you can read from the code above that you were implementing a version control and can implement a new version control for that major release. Perhaps with the try/except, implementing another version control for a third option wouldn't be the way to go about it. I think both answers are acceptable for the two revisions of python currently available.

Answer (score 2):

I use following code to prevent global namespace pollution:

```py
import unittest
try:
    import unittest.mock
except ImportError:
    import mock
    unittest.mock = mock
```